# Understanding Attribute Ends With Selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to understand the selector in this specific bit of code. I understand the attribute ends with selector part, but why include the beginning of the id.

```
$('#ctl00_CPH1_datalistPriceTypeQty [id$="_lblMembershipPriceType"]').each(function() {
    if($(this).text().indexOf('kjh') >= 0){
        $(this).parentsUntil('span').hide();
    }
});
```

The full id it points to is "ctl00_CPH1_datalistPriceTypeQty_ctl01_lblMembershipPriceType"

Is there a reason to include the beginning of the id and not just use *? If so is there a reason to break it at a specific point

Comment: The selector is in two parts; the first part selects elements with the id "ctl00_CPH1_datalistPriceTypeQty" exactly. The second part matches descendants of that element if their id ends with "_lblMembershipPriceType". The two parts have nothing to do with each other except that elements matched by the second half must be descendants of the element matched by the first.